# Google Kubernetes Engine Ingress doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Create ingress followed the guide of 'Kubernetes in Action' book on GKE, but the ingress doesn't work, can' be accessed from the public IP address of Ingress.

1. Create the replicaset to create pod.
2. Create Service. (followed the nodeport method on 'Kubernetes in Action').
3. Create ingress.

ReplicaSet, Service, Ingress are created successfully, nodeport can be accessed from the public IP address, no UNHEALTHY in ingress.

replicaset:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: kubia
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubia
  template:
    metadata:
        labels:
          app: kubia
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubia
        image: sonyfaye/kubia
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubia-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30123
  selector:
    app: kubia
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubia
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubia.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend: 
          serviceName: kubia-nodeport
          servicePort: 80
```

The nodeport itself can be accessed from public IP addresses.

C:\kube>kubectl get svc

```
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.59.240.1    <none>        443/TCP        8d
kubia-nodeport   NodePort    10.59.253.10   <none>        80:30123/TCP   20h
```

C:\kube>kubectl get node

```
NAME                                   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
gke-kubia-default-pool-08dd2133-qbz6   Ready    <none>   8d    v1.12.8-gke.6
gke-kubia-default-pool-183639fa-18vr   Ready    <none>   8d    v1.12.8-gke.6
gke-kubia-default-pool-42725220-43q8   Ready    <none>   8d    v1.12.8-gke.6
```

C:\kube>kubectl get node -o wide

```
NAME                                   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION         INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP      OS-IMAGE                             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
gke-kubia-default-pool-08dd2133-qbz6   Ready    <none>   8d    v1.12.8-gke.6   10.140.0.17   35.201.224.238   Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.119+        docker://17.3.2
gke-kubia-default-pool-183639fa-18vr   Ready    <none>   8d    v1.12.8-gke.6   10.140.0.18   35.229.152.12    Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.119+        docker://17.3.2
gke-kubia-default-pool-42725220-43q8   Ready    <none>   8d    v1.12.8-gke.6   10.140.0.16   34.80.225.64     Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.119+        docker://17.3.2
```

C:\kube>curl http://34.80.225.64:30123

```
You've hit kubia-j2lnr
```

But the ingress can't be accessed from outside.

hosts file:

```
34.98.92.110 kubia.example.com
```

C:\kube>kubectl describe ingress

```
Name:             kubia
Namespace:        default
Address:          34.98.92.110
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.56.0.7:8080)
Rules:
  Host               Path  Backends
  ----               ----  --------
  kubia.example.com
                     /   kubia-nodeport:80 (10.56.0.14:8080,10.56.1.6:8080,10.56.3.4:8080)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:         {"k8s-be-30123--c4addd497b1e0a6d":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-30594--c4addd497b1e0a6d":"HEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:  k8s-fw-default-kubia--c4addd497b1e0a6d
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:     k8s-tp-default-kubia--c4addd497b1e0a6d
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:          k8s-um-default-kubia--c4addd497b1e0a6d
Events:    

                               <none>
```

C:\kube>curl http://kubia.example.com

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to kubia.example.com port 80: Timed out
```

C:\kube>telnet kubia.example.com 80

```
Connecting To kubia.example.com...
```

C:\kube>telnet 34.98.92.110 80

```
Connecting To 34.98.92.110...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed
```

Tried from intranet.
curl 34.98.92.110 IP can get some resule, and 80 port of 34.98.92.110 is accessible from intranet.

C:\kube>kubectl exec -it kubia-lrt9x bash

```
root@kubia-lrt9x:/# curl http://kubia.example.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: kubia.example.com
```

root@kubia-lrt9x:/# curl http://34.98.92.110
`default backend - 404`root@kubia-lrt9x:/# curl http://34.98.92.110
`default backend - 404`root@kubia-lrt9x:/#
root@kubia-lrt9x:/# curl http://10.56.0.7:8080
`default backend - 404`root@kubia-lrt9x:/#

Does anybody know how to debug this?

The nodeport is been added to the firewall, or else nodeport is not accessible. The Ingress IP seems don't need to be added to the firewall.

Comment: have you mapped ingress ip address to DNS record ?

Comment: Thanks, Harsh. Yes, I did. In my case, using the hosts file to map hosts file:

34.98.92.110 kubia.example.com. The problem is, the ingress ip's 80 port can't be accessed from internet, but can from the kubernetes intranet. It yeild out default backend - 404 to intranet accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to expose replicaset to be able to connect from the outside:

```
$ kubectl expose rs hello-world --type=NodePort --name=my-service
```

remember to first delete service kubia-nodeport and delete selector and section with service in Ingress configuration file and then apply changes using **kubectl apply** command.

More information you can find here: [exposing-externalip](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/).

Useful doc: [kubectl-expose](https://www.mankier.com/1/kubectl-expose#Example).